# Send request over mobile network in iOS

Tags: ios, sockets, inputstream, outputstream

In one of my application I need to make HTTP request on 2G/3g/4g only. If device is connected to Wifi and mobile data both, I need to route the request to mobile data. I don't want to turn ON/OFF Wifi.

Apple does not provide this in high level API's but it can be done using low level socket programming where we can transfer the traffic on cellular if both networks are available.

Any sample code or tutorial link will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Socket programming is not used for sending HTTP request.

Socket request you can not redirect to mobile data or wifi. it will work on whichever network is connected. this is OS level point.

In terms of "low level socket programming" means, Socket used to broadcast data for example which users are online / offline and you need to know without calling an API then you can use socket, socket architecture on server will send data on online / offline user to devices without making request from device.

So using socket would not help you and there is no provision that you can redirect your your request to mobile data or wifi.

Comment: Thanks @hasya. But I am able to send and receive the GET Request using send() & recv() API.

Comment: how did you do it @b